# What's wrong with response in Volley?

Tags: android, android-volley

I used Volley to send a request to the backend, and sometimes I debug and see that it's response error and ok. I don't know why this happens. Thank for your help to explain me this case.

Comment: Can you post your code plz ? -_-

Comment: response error and ok for one request?

Comment: yes, just one request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is problem of retry function in Volley, if you did not set retry for request, it will automatically retry sending another request if wait for response too long. You can set policy for request in Volley like this

```
 StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) 
            {
                //response OK
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                //response Error
            }
        })
        {
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams()
            {
                return  getParams();
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError 
            { 
                return  getHeaders();
            }
        };
        sr.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10),//time out in 10second
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,//DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES = 1;
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
                getRequestQueue().add(sr);
```

Comment: sorry for my unclear question, i will try this. Thanks for your reply

Comment: it works as a charm. Turn out it auto retry sending request. Thank you alot

Comment: you're welcome, i got the same problem with you, so i think this will help you.